# changing the Animations of UpdatePanelAnimationExtender programmatically only works on first postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the animations programmatically for an existing UpdatePanelAnimationExtender control.  It only updates the .Animations method the first time it hits Page_Init .

Here is what I have done so far.

Step 1. Create an UpdatePanelAnimationExtender (This assumes you already have an UpdatePanel created) in the aspx page:

```
        <cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="UpdatePanel1" Enabled="True" >
    <Animations>

                    <OnUpdated>

                    <Sequence>

                        <Parallel duration="0">
                            <ScriptAction Script="alert('test1');" />
                        </Parallel> 

                    </Sequence>

                    </OnUpdated>
    </Animations>
</cc1:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

Step 2, from Page_Init (In code behind), attempt to change the alert javascript method:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        // Gets a reference to a control inside a ContentPlaceHolder
        ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
        mpContentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("MainContent");
        if (mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
        {
            UpdatePanelAnimationExtender uae = (UpdatePanelAnimationExtender)mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1");

            if (uae != null)
            {

                uae.Enabled = true;

                uae.Animations = "<OnUpdated>" +
                                 "<Sequence>" +
                                 "<Parallel duration=\"0\">" +
                                 "<ScriptAction Script=\"alert('" + DateTime.Now + "');\" />" +
                                 "</Parallel>" +
                                 "</Sequence>" +
                                 "</OnUpdated>";

            }
        }

    }
```

You will notice the first time it runs it updates the time on the message box, any subsequent calls do not update the time.  Why is the time not updated and how can this be resolved?

Thanks Before Hand

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

What's is rendered on the client side is whatever the value of `DateTime.Now` was or is. It isn't a dynamic method call but one created once.

Try calling the javascript version of DateTime.Now instead.